# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: How do I require a specifc version of a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

currently, I have

```
 config.gem 'gem_name', :version => "0.1"
```

but, i think that means at least this version.

How do I specify: exactly this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this isn't really an answer but the code you have written is for the exact version. If it was for 'at least this version' it would look like:

```
config.gem 'gem_name', :version => ">=0.1"
```

And if you wanted to specify a range that your version would fall into, it would be:

```
config.gem 'gem_name', :version => ['>= 0.1', '< 1.1']
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use Bundler with Rails: http://gembundler.com/rails23.html

If you go the Bundler route, you can specify your exact version in your `Gemfile`.

If you decide not to use Bundler, you can also specify the gem version before you require the gem, instead of doing `config.gem ...`:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'gem_name', "= 0.1"
require 'gem_name'
```